# Handling different ethnicity groups in a work without stepping into racism or faux multiculturalism

Tags: creative-writing, technique, characters, tropes

**Faux Multiculturalism:** When people come are from a different part of the world is not even remotely reflected on their personalities.

**Racism:** Falling into ethnic stereotypes.

I want to handle different ethnicities in my story, but without stepping into either of those, the current consensus on that is:

> As I said, I don't give a f@ck about your ethnicity. Now go out there, and check if those robots are currently not being hacked by a basement dwelling parasite.

*-The anti-hero main character's opinion on this topic*

However, I still feel like that **this is not enough**, and it doesn't cover the field entirely. **I want to have characters whose personality reflects the place where they born and/or lived most of their lives**, because **that is influential to everyone**, regardless of race.

**So, how can I pull that off, without stepping into Faux multiculturalism or getting accused of racism?**

*For instance, Hari Seldon from the Foundation series sometimes mentions a thing or two about Helicon, his home planet. Also, in the prequel novels, his lack of knowledge about Mycogen district's customs gets him into a smaller trouble.*

Comment: I do get what you are trying to say and you are right to say it is balanced between all races who show both tolerance and intolerance towards each other.  I would consider looking at Coach Boone from remember the titans.  He pretty much had the same attitude as your sample quote with the goal of getting a team to work united together despite heavy racism.  I think as long as you treat everyone equally and give each race the same i don't give a hoot about your color, it would still get your point across while showing equality to their ability and not colors.

Comment: @ggiaquin But this situation violates the law of conservation of detail, which states: "If the gun is not gonna be fired, it shouldn't be hanging there."

Comment: There's a good question in here, but it's obscured by the provocation and politicizing.  I encourage you to ask this question without that.

Comment: @MonicaCellio PTSD aside, can you be a bit more precise? I'd currently close your comment as too broad and unclear what you're asking...

Comment: I'm voting to close this as I really don't see a craft question here. It seems to be asking either what opinion you should express, or how not to get into trouble for expressing the opinion you hold, neither of which are craft questions. If I had a clearer idea of what the craft question was, I would be tempted to answer, write people, not races. But I'm not clear if that is the actually relevant to your question.

Comment: BTW, your law of conservation of detail is silly. You might as well say that a tree should not be there if you are not going to get hung from it. Detail speaks to setting and character, you don't have to use every blessed thing you mention.

Comment: @RedactedRedacted I'll demonstrate with an edit.  (I see you already figured out part of the problem on your own.)  The "quote" from one of your characters seems to be an example of one of the things you wanted to avoid, by the way; I don't see what that adds at all, so I cut that out too.  It would help if you would [edit] to add what you've tried already and to add *relevant* information per Mark's comments.

Comment: @MonicaCellio Thou shall not invalidate comments with your edits.

Comment: @MarkBaker Every detail should have some function in a story, or character. And you will not go into a lengthy detail the beautiful forest in the middle of a fight scene because that ruins the pacing, which has a priority over the minuscule advantages of that description.

Comment: Some function, sure. But to suggest that a gun should not be hanging on the wall unless it is going to go off is silly. A gun hanging on the wall may simply be a scene setting detail. And in many works richness of detail is the reward in itself. It is one of the principal charms of the Aubrey/Maturin novels by Patrick O'Brien, for instance.

Comment: @MarkBaker Does it have a function? Is it not getting in the priority's way? If yes, yes, then it doesn't violate the laws. *I hope he realized, that the gun quote was a metaphor...*

Comment: @RedactedRedacted If all it means is every word should have a function, then we already have that principle, making it entirely redundant. As stated, though, it is saying something much more specific, which is don't introduce a prop unless you intend to use it, which is at least distinct, if insupportable. And no, the gun quote is not a metaphor. If you are trying to illustrate a principle (these are not laws by any reasonable meaning of the word) then you use an example, not a metaphor. And what would it be a metaphor for?

Comment: @MarkBaker It is a metaphor for:  "If it has no purpose, then cut it because the readers will drop the book if you bore them with unnecessary details."

Comment: @RedactedRedacted. That is not what a metaphor is.

Comment: @RedactedRedacted thou shalt not ascribe more importance to comments than what is due.  Comments are to improve the post (such as by asking for clarification or improvement).  Nothing in a comment "protects" a post from editing.  There is no concept on SE of "invalidating" comments; comments are temporary post-it notes.  We're concerned about invalidating *answers*, which is why we put unclear/broad/opinion-based questions on hold until the problems are fixed (so they don't attract answers in the meantime that would prevent improvements).  Comments...are not that.

Comment: *"But this situation violates the law of conservation of detail, which states: "If the gun is not gonna be fired, it shouldn't be hanging there.""* There is another adage which is well worth learning: *Rules are meant to be broken.* Just because something is listed on TV Tropes doesn't *automatically* make it a bad story-telling device. However, before you start breaking rules, or using tropes, you first need to learn what the rule or trope is, when it applies, and *why* it applies, in order to break it *effectively and for a purpose*.

Comment: @MonicaCellio Well, I guess you *could* argue that it's invalidating a comment if the comment could legitimately be flagged *obsolete* after making a change to the post it's attached to. Of course nowadays, that same thing is called *no longer needed* because... reasons? Of course, in that sense and in my not always entirely humble opinion, invalidating comments is a *good* thing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't explain well how the ethnicity of the different ethnic groups is relevant to your novel.

Think of a novel set at a university. You could tell a realistic tale of love, politics, and science, without once mentioning the fact that your characters come from all over the world. In the science community, science (and individual traits) are more important than the cultural background of a person, simply because the groups are sometimes composed of as many cultures as people, so that whatever ethnic traits they bring in are considered personal.

In this example, you would simply not bring up the fact of the characters' ethnicity at all, maybe even leave your readers in doubt about the color of some of the characters' skin. Some authors have surprised their readers by bringing up ethnicity very late in a book or never. A famous example is Ursula K. Le Guin's *Earthsea* trilogy. In this, when you read it (and are a white person), you automatically assume that the protagonists are the typical white mages of fantasy fiction. But then Le Guin explains in interviews, and looking back at the novels you are surprised that you agree, that most of the characters in the books are like Native Americans. It comes quite as a shock, that you overlooked that through the racial bias that you have, and I like that a lot.

Or think of a novel set in New York. You can tell of city life and mention the different customs of the Russian, Chinese, Jewish, and Irish communities, how people from these communities live and work together but still form part of those communities and keep them alive. People in New York (usually) get along well and respect their differences just as they respect individual differences within their group. In a story set there, ethnicity must be mentioned, because it is an important part of the life of that city, but like New York that mix of cultures is neither problematic nor unproblematic, neither viewed (by most of the New Yorkers) as something to undo nor as something to stive for. It simply is, like the weather, and is treated the same way: you try not to get wet, but you get on with life.

If you want to deal with ethnicities without racism or multiculturalism, just treat it in your novel like your would treat any other difference between people.

Do you make a big deal out of your characters' differing body height? No. Do you constantly mention that they like different foods, vote for different parties, or have different preferences in sex? Not if your book is not about one of these.

So why do you feel you need to make a big deal about "race" or "ethnicity"? Both, by the way, concepts, that the world outside the US has largely abandoned (compare, for example, the [German](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_(human_categorization)) and [English](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rassentheorie) version of the Wikipedia article on theories about human races).

If you have different ethnic groups in your book, *and they get along*, just deal with their ethinicity in the same way that you would with people from this and that side of town: you would mention that John came from East Newtown and Joan from West Newtown, and then have them interact like all us different people do.

If they don't get along, and the conflict is caused by their ethnic backround, then explain how that is so. But still portray everyone like a normal person, with good sides and bad, with prejudices and tolerance, trying to be fair, but failing.

The solution, in other words is:

#### Don't portray your characters as stereotypes, but make them real.

Real people are usually neither racists, nor much excited by multiculturalism. They have many conflicting emotions and opinions, they want to help, but remain safe, they are curious and afraid, they can be generous and cruel – it is all in us! And depending on the situation, one or the other will come to the forefront and inform our actions.

Comment: I was going to answer but, after reading this, there's no point. I'll just add something a teacher of mine once said: if you must mention be careful mentioning other cultures, it's because those cultures are not viewed as equal. So if you want to treat your characters as equal, one should avoid calling the reader's attentions to cultural biases as it will unconsciously say they are different and, therefore, not necessarily equal. However, you can refer to such differences casually, normally, to counteract that effect. For example, you can write that Anne and her friends sat in a restaurant...

Comment: ... to celebrate Joe's birthday. Anne looks over the menu of the day  - meat crunchy - then checks what type of meat. Oh, pork. So she asks for a steak. You don't even have to say why right then. The simple casual act of checking the type of meat, that someone who doesn't est must do, is enough to start characterising Anne.